# Differences between realization of the random variable and deterministic variable?

Tags: random-variable, variable, deterministic

1. The first question is that can we classify variable into **random variable** and **deterministic variable**?
2. The second question is that **The possible values taken by a random variable"X"(Uppercase)** are termed as **realizations of random variable"x"(Lowercase letter)**. 
   These "realizations" lose randomness. 
   **So in summary, can we say that the realizations of random variable"x" is a kind of deterministic variable?**

Comment: By reviewing [some of our posts about random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22random+variable%22+score%3A10+is%3Aanswer+) you should be able to get some clarification about these distinctions.

Comment: The reason why I have this problem is that i get confused about the differences between realization of the random variable and deterministic variable from "https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109085/notation-deterministic-variable-random-variable-realization-of-random-variabl?rq=1" I think realisation of the random variable is one kind of deterministic variable. Is it reasonable?

Comment: You might be confused by the common word "variable."  A random variable is a *function* and it's perfectly deterministic.  A variable is a term in a formal mathematical expression; it could refer to any kind of mathematical object, but in the most elementary situations it refers to an unknown *number.*  That's why researching the definition of a random variable is likely to help answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. 'Can we' - risky phrasing there. You certainly *can*, whether that is useful for your purposes is a question you need to ask yourself. Any deterministic variable behaves like a stochastic variable with a probability of 100%, so you might want to just think of it as a special case.
2. The realizations of a random variable may well *also* be random variables, so it's not a sufficient criterion.

Comment: Sorry for my expression firstly. In the second question, what I want to express is that "after we receive the information that the random variable X has taken a certain value x (i.e., X=x), the value x is called the realization of X". So it means that x is not random. In this situation,is it reasonable to say that x is a deterministic variable?

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just potentially misleading. Your realization may be a parameter of a probability distribution with its own set of potential outcomes; calling the realization a deterministic variable runs the risk of muddying up which one of these you're talking about.

Comment: Re 2: This strange statement makes me wonder what you mean by "realizations."  Do you have a specific definition in mind?  Could you provide an example where a realization of a random variable is a random variable?